# Replace or remove bibliography numbers

Tags: bibliographies, numbering

I'm using a simple bibliography like this

```
...
\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{acm}
\bibliography{refs}
...
```

and I would like to either replace the numbers ([1], [2], ...) in front of each reference with some other symbol (e.g. dots) or just remove them altogether.

Any ideas?

**Edit**: I am using the article class.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

To change the label, you can redefine `\@biblabel`; for example, to use a bullet you can say in the preamble:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@biblabel[1]{\textbullet}
\makeatother
```

to suppress the label, use:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@biblabel[1]{}
\makeatother
```

this, however, will preserve indentation. To remove this indentation you can redefine the `thebibliography` environment (which is basically a list); this redefinition depends on the document class used (and you didn't mention this in your question).

Here's an example of such a redefinition for the `article` document class:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@biblabel[1]{}
\renewenvironment{thebibliography}[1]
     {\section*{\refname}%
      \@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\refname}{\MakeUppercase\refname}%
      \list{}%
           {\leftmargin0pt
            \@openbib@code
            \usecounter{enumiv}}%
      \sloppy
      \clubpenalty4000
      \@clubpenalty \clubpenalty
      \widowpenalty4000%
      \sfcode`\.\@m}
     {\def\@noitemerr
       {\@latex@warning{Empty `thebibliography' environment}}%
      \endlist}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{acm}
\bibliography{biblio}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Both work like a charm! Thanks a lot! (I was indeed using article.)

Comment: I am having the same issue but I am using a book document class. Could you help me by providing a working example of how to remove this indentation in this class? I am LATEX enthusiast but not very good at code writing. Regards Rod

Comment: @RodrigoEsteves [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Your question won't be seen by many people here, so it would be best to repost it as a fresh question. [Follow-up questions](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2117/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-post-a-follow-up-question-why-and-how) like this are more than welcome! Please use the "Ask Question" link for your new question; there you can link to this question to provide the background.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina I noticed that the top two code blocks actually don't preserve indentation, I don't know why...

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}`, then you can remove the  `[numbers]` part to remove numbering.