# List References with No Numbering

Tags: biblatex

For a paper I am working on, I am managing my citations with biblatex. I don't use in text citations, so I am currently using the command `\nocite{*}` to print all references.

However, the output is numbered. Since I am not actually referring to any of them in the text, I would prefer if it were simply an alphabetical list, with no numbers next to each reference.

Is there a simple way to do so? I couldn't find anything in the documentation that seemed like it would help.

Update: Just found [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35369/replace-or-remove-bibliography-numbers). However, biblatex doesn't seem to use `@biblabel`. Looking into it.

Comment: Why not use a non-numeric style? `authortitle` generates the same bibliography entries as the numeric styles, but without the label numbers.

Comment: @Audrey You mean `authoryear`? I was trying to avoid `authoryear` because in another section I do use the numeric style. If I can't figure it out, that might be what I end up doing though.

Comment: No, `authortitle`. You can't use multiple styles in one document, but you can use different bibliography environments via the `env` option to `\printbibligraphy`.

Comment: @Audrey I was not aware of that style, but that seems like exactly what I was looking for. Thank you