# Bibtex bibliography without numbers, sorted and with indents

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

[I am actually reposting a modified version of my older question because I wasn't able to solve it myself]

I am trying to generate a german bibliography using Bibtex. Here are some three examples of my items:

```
@book{Kirchgässner-Wolters-2007,
  AUTHOR        = "Kirchgässner, Gebhard and Wolters, Jürgen",
  EDITOR        = "",
  TITLE         = "Introduction to Modern Time Series Analysis",
  language      = "",
  edition       = "1",
  series        = "",
  address       = "",
  PUBLISHER     = "Springer",
  month         = "",
  YEAR          = "2007",
  volume        = "",
  number        = "",
  note          = "",
  url           = ""
}


@unpublished{Chun-Lin-2010,
  AUTHOR        = "Chun-Lin, Liu",
  TITLE         = "A Tutorial of the Wavelet Transform",
  language      = "",
  month         = "February",
  year          = "2010",
  NOTE          = "unpublished",
  url           = ""
}

 @misc{Hyndman-Athamasopoulos-2012,
   author = "Hyndman, Rob J. and Athanasopoulos, George",
   title = "Forecasting: principles and practice",
   year = "2012",
   url = "https://www.otexts.org/book/fpp",
   note = "[Online; accessed 21-February-2014]"
 }
```

The code I used is this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,10pt]{report}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc}
\usepackage[german]{babelbib} 

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\bibliography{bibtemplate} 
\bibliographystyle{babunsrt}


\end{document}
```

This results in the following bibliography:

[image]

I would like to have it without numbers but instead sorted according to the first authors name and with indents for the following lines of the same item. I would like to solve it **without biblatex**.

I find some solutions for one problem, but the others remain unsolved or it rusuls in new problems.

I would be grateful for any help!

Comment: Have you tried using the bibliography style `apalike`?

Comment: @Ryan Hi Ryan, just did it, but don't really like the result. I would like to have no number or anything else at all. Just sort by the authors name

Comment: Well, darn. MiKTeX repositories are down for maintenance, so I can't download the `babelbib` package to give it a run. I'll try again later.

Comment: In the meantime, have you looked at this one: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35369/replace-or-remove-bibliography-numbers

Comment: Look very good! The result look almost as I want them. The only thing is that there are no indents.

Comment: Have you tried using `makebst`? It should be available from your command line, and will present you with a bunch of options for your bibliography. Once you pick all your options, it will generate the style for you.