# How to use vancouver citation style with biber/biblatex?

Tags: biblatex, citing, biber

i know how to use the vancouver citation style with bibtex, but i use biber in my project, but i don't know how to use the vancouver citation style there?

i configured my tex file like this and added my bib file:

```
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}
```

I tried it with the commands but did not work:

```
style=vancouver 
citestyle=vancouver
```

I got only an error that the `\cite` command is not defined. So it seems that the citation style could not be found or loaded. So can someone help me to get the vancouver style working?

Thanks!

Comment: As far as I know there is no fully-fledged "Vancouver" style for `biblatex` out there. There is a BibTeX (`.bst`) style ([here on CTAN](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/biblio/bibtex/contrib/vancouver)). See also [Vancouver citation style in LaTex](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/203607/35864). If you don't have a `.bbx`/`.cbx` pair the `style=vancouver` option cannot help you.

Comment: Here are the bibtex style: https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/biblio/bibtex/contrib/vancouver?lang=de and here general information about the vancouver style: https://blackboard.swan.ac.uk/bbcswebdav/institution/LibraryISSResources/Referencing%20Guides/brief%20referencing%20guide%20for%20Vancouver%20oct%202012.pdf

Comment: The style you link to cannot be used with `biblatex` it is a BibTeX style. Note also that what is considered Vancouver style may vary quite a bit from institution to institution.

Comment: yes i know that i can not use the bibtex style i posted with biblatex. My question is how to use it with biblatex or is there a predefined style i can use? yes right the style vary a bit from institution to institution

Comment: If with "it" you mean the `.bst` style the answer is *you cannot use it with `biblatex`*, if you refer to the general concept of the "Vancouver style", then my comment above applies that I don't know about a full implementation of that style for `biblatex`. The pre-defined `numeric` style might come close to what you want, but you will probably have to apply (quite) some modifications. You could of course stop using `biblatex` and go for good old BibTeX and use `vancouver.bst`.

Comment: okay. yes bibtex could be an alternative, but i thought i use biblates/biber because they more up2date and could better handle utf8, etc.

Comment: Normally, I recommend `biblatex` over BibTeX, but if you have a `.bst` style that suits your needs (and you are mainly writing in English), you can stick to BibTeX. If you want to use `biblatex` you need to accept that currently there is no ready-to-use Vancouver style out there, so you will have to roll your own (starting from `numeric` I suppose).

Comment: ok, i will try it with numeric and will see and maybe made some changes to it. thanks.

Comment: Vancouver style just means numeric citations, just like Harvard style usually means author date; without any specifics. So, that being said, Vancouver is biblatexs default.

Comment: oh good to know that numeric likes Vancouver style. As i said it before i will try it and maybe modify it.

Answer (score 8):

The term "Vancouver style" or "Vancouver system" seems to be slightly more variable than say, APA style or Chicago style.
Often institutions have their own modifications to the general idea of the style. 
(Much like "Harvard style" often just means an author year style.)

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vancouver_system) the home of the "official Vancouver style" is the NLM's [Citing Medicine](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK7256/).

From what I can see there, it is essentially a numerical style.

For BibTeX there is [`vancouver.bst`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/vancouver).

For `biblatex` a quick search on the web only turned up https://github.com/fluffels/biblatex-vancouver, the styles there haven't been updated in years though and the redefinitions of the drivers are indeed quite rough. See also [Vancouver citation style in LaTex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/203607/35864).

I think your best bet with `biblatex` is to start from a `numeric` style and modify it as needed. One prominent feature is the name format which can be reproduced with `terseinits=true, firstinits=true` and

```
\DeclareNameAlias{default}{last-first}
\renewcommand*{\revsdnamepunct}{}
```

---

As Johannes_B points out in the comments, there is [Biblatex style file for New England Journal of Medicine (NEJM)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/26891/35864) which lead to [`biblatex-nejm`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-nejm). And indeed what [Marco Daniel](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/5239/marco-daniel) implements there seems quite close to the Vancouver style requirements linked to above.

The package has been last updated in November 2011 though, and so some of the code might not work that smoothly. From what I could see most of it is still absolutely the right code for the job. The `\renewbibmacro*{name:last-first}` block, however, can be replaced by the code above.

Comment: I didn't look at the pdfs that explain the style, but i just came across [Biblatex style file for New England Journal of Medicine (NEJM)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/26891) Seems to be a good start.

Comment: @Johannes_B Good call, indeed the NEJM's [Uniform Requirements for Manuscripts Submitted to Biomedical Journals](http://www.nejm.org/doi/full/10.1056/NEJM199102073240624) is about the Vancouver style, so I'm quite confident that this is more or less what the NEJM uses. `biblatex-nejm` is, however, more than four years old, so I'm not sure if it still works smoothly. Most of the suggestions in the answer are definitely still good to use.

Comment: M'arco hasnt been online for a while. Maybe Stefan can ping him, if somehing doesn't work. Or just opening a github issue would be fine.

Comment: @Johannes_B I haven't tested the style, so I cannot say anything about how it works. Four years is a long time in `biblatex` development; but the code I looked at it was absolutely fine except for the `\renewbibmacro*{name:last-first}` block, which I believe could be replaced by `\renewcommand*{\revsdnamepunct}{}`.

Comment: @Johannes_B I have left an issue at github.

Comment: `firstinits=true` has been deprecated. It should be replaced with `giveninits=true`.

Comment: @daviewales Indeed, also `\DeclareNameAlias{default}{last-first}` should be `\DeclareNameAlias{default}{family-given}`. See [`biblatex` 3.3 name formatting](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/299036/35864)