# Render fake bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, bibitem

in my latex document I have two bibliographies. First is for theoretical part of thesis and second is my articles. I don't want to reference or cite from the second bibliography. Is there a way how to create (render) a fake bibliography without bibliography command ? I mean I want only render this without numbering :

\bibitem{blabla}
Jon Doe
\newblock {Article title}.
\newblock {\em SpringerPlus}, 2015.

Thank you for your responses in advance.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436)! Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Does this help? https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/35371/120578 ?

Comment: Firstly I thought that this could not be the solution for my problem. However it actually is. Thank you very much for your help.