# remove bibliography numbers with indentation

Tags: bibliographies

I am creating a manual Bibliography using

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twosided]{report}
```

and this post works fine for me [Replace or remove bibliography numbers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35369/replace-or-remove-bibliography-numbers)

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@biblabel[1]{}
\renewenvironment{thebibliography}[1]
     {\section*{\refname}%
      \@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\refname}{\MakeUppercase\refname}%
      \list{}%
           {\leftmargin0pt
            \@openbib@code
            \usecounter{enumiv}}%
      \sloppy
      \clubpenalty4000
      \@clubpenalty \clubpenalty
      \widowpenalty4000%
      \sfcode`\.\@m}
     {\def\@noitemerr
       {\@latex@warning{Empty `thebibliography' environment}}%
      \endlist}
\makeatother
```

Except that now I want that each entry does not have a hanging indentation after the first line at each entry.

I have used the following manual bibliography

```
\begin{thebibliography}{100}

\bibitem{Aadnoy1988} Aadnoy, B. S. (1988). Modeling of the Stability of Highly Inclined Boreholes in Anisotropic Rock Formations (includes associated papers 19213 and 19886 ). \textit{SPE Drilling Engineering}, 3(03), 259–268.

\bibitem{Aadnoy2003} Aadnoy, B. S., & Ong, S. (2003). Introduction to special issue on Borehole Stability. Journal of Petroleum Science and Engineering, 38(3–4), 79–82.

\end{thebibliography}
```

I would expect to see as per the snapshot below.
[image]

Comment: Please clarify what you would like to get. Did interpret your comment correct that you wish to have hanging indentation? Please also state which document class you employ.

Comment: I am using \documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twosided]{report}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twosided]{report} 

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@biblabel[1]{}
\renewenvironment{thebibliography}[1]
     {\section*{\bibname}% report class uses \bibname instead of \refname
      \@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\refname}{\MakeUppercase\refname}%
      \list{}%
           {\settowidth\leftmargin{#1}%
            \itemindent=-\leftmargin
            \@openbib@code
            \usecounter{enumiv}}%
      \sloppy
      \clubpenalty4000
      \@clubpenalty \clubpenalty
      \widowpenalty4000%
      \sfcode`\.\@m}
     {\def\@noitemerr
       {\@latex@warning{Empty `thebibliography' environment}}%
      \endlist}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{thebibliography}{100}

\bibitem{Aadnoy1988} Aadnoy, B. S. (1988). Modeling of the Stability of Highly Inclined Boreholes in Anisotropic Rock Formations (includes associated papers 19213 and 19886 ). \textit{SPE Drilling Engineering}, 3(03), 259–268.

\bibitem{Aadnoy2003} Aadnoy, B. S., \& Ong, S. (2003). Introduction to special issue on Borehole Stability. Journal of Petroleum Science and Engineering, 38(3–4), 79–82.

\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It works very well!