# moderncv with apsrev bibliographystyle gives unwanted author brackets

Tags: bibliographies, moderncv

Here is a MWE of my problem:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{classic}
\moderncvcolor{black}
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}
\name{John}{Doe}

\begin{document}

\makecvtitle
\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{apsrev4-1}
\bibliography{mwe}
\end{document}
```

with the referenced .bib file

```
@article{MyArticle,
title = {A Fancy Title},
author = {Doe, John},
journal = {Prestigous Journal},
volume = {2},
issue = {3},
pages = {038952},
year = {2020},
month = {Jul},
}
```

which outputs the following file:
[image]

The [Doe(2020)] at the beginning of the reference is not present with other bibliography styles, and I would like to remove it. How do I do this?

Comment: Try the solution from here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/35371/90297

Comment: Did the given link in the comment solve your issue?

Answer (score 1):

To get rid of the complete label simply add the following lines in your preamble (possibility 1):

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@biblabel[1]{} % <========================== possibility 1
%\renewcommand\@biblabel[1]{\textbullet} % <============== possibility 2
\makeatother
```

If you want instead the label an for example textbullet to mark the beginning of a new bib entry you can use possibility 2 like

```
\makeatletter
%\renewcommand\@biblabel[1]{} % <========================== possibility 1
\renewcommand\@biblabel[1]{\textbullet} % <============== possibility 2
\makeatother
```

With the following MWE (uses `filecontents` to add the bib file in the compilable mwe)

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@Book{Goossens,
  author    = {Goossens, Michel and Mittelbach, Frank and 
               Samarin, Alexander},
  title     = {The LaTeX Companion},
  edition   = {1},
  publisher = {Addison-Wesley},
  location  = {Reading, Mass.},
  year      = {1994},
}
@Book{adams,
  title     = {The Restaurant at the End of the Universe},
  author    = {Douglas Adams},
  series    = {The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy},
  publisher = {Pan Macmillan},
  year      = {1980},
}
@article{feynman,
  title     = {Very High-Energy Collisions of Hadrons},
  author    = {Richard P. Feynman},
  journal   = {Phys. Rev. Lett.},
  volume    = {23},
  issue     = {24},
  pages     = {1415--1417},
  year      = {1969},
  month     = {Dec},
  doi       = {10.1103/PhysRevLett.23.1415},
  url       = {http://link.aps.org/doi/10.1103/PhysRevLett.23.1415},
  publisher = {American Physical Society},
}
@article{MyArticle,
  title   = {A Fancy Title},
  author  = {Doe, John},
  journal = {Prestigous Journal},
  volume  = {2},
  issue   = {3},
  pages   = {038952},
  year    = {2020},
  month   = {Jul},
}
\end{filecontents*}


\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{classic}
\moderncvcolor{black}
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}
\name{John}{Doe}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@biblabel[1]{} % <========================== possibility 1
%\renewcommand\@biblabel[1]{\textbullet} % <============== possibility 2
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\makecvtitle
\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{apsrev4-1} % 
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

you get the resulting pdf

[image: resulting pdf without labels]

With possibility 2 you get the following resulting pdf:

[image: resulting pdf with text bullets]